# User cannot login in Angular js with JWT and Node API

Tags: angularjs, node.js, api, jwt

I am creating a Node api for user login and am using JSON web Token for authentication.

```
apiRoutes.put('/login', function(req, res){
  User.findOne({name:req.body.name}, function(err, user){
    if(err){throw err;}
    else{
      if(!user){
        res.send({success:false, msg:'Auth Failed'});
      }else{
        user.comparePassword(req.body.password, function(err, isMatch){
          if(isMatch && !err){
            var token=jwt.encode(user, config.secret);
            res.json({success:true, token:'JWT' +token});
          }else{
            res.send({success:false, msg:'Auth Fails:wrong password'});
          }
        });
      }
    }
  });
});
```

**Login Controller**

```
app.controller('loginCtrl', function($http, $scope, $location, $cookieStore){

 $scope.login=function(){ 
    console.log($scope.loginUser);
    $http.put('/api/login', $scope.loginUser).then(function(response){

        console.log(response.data.token); 
        $cookieStore.put('token',response.data.token);
        $scope.currentUser=$scope.loginUser.name;  
        alert("Successfully Loggedin");

       }, function(err){
       alert('Bad Login Credentials');
      });

      };
    });
```

**Login form HTML**

```
<div class="post" ng-controller="loginCtrl">  
        <form method="post">
          <div class="form-group" >
          <label>Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" ng-model="loginUser.name" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Password</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" ng-model="loginUser.password"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="login()" >Login</button>
        </div>
        </form>

      </div>
```

The problem is that, when I click on the login button with the user credentials, it is always returning `alert("successfully logged in");`, despite the user credentials being right or wrong. I think there is something missing in the Angular Login controller, but I am unable to find out the error.

Can someone help me out to find the issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

When you are sending error response try to send http status code in response. Just try to send

```
res.send(400, {success:false, msg:'Auth Failed'});
```

Comment: with express 4 use res.status(400).send({success:false, msg:'Auth Failed'});

Comment: if user `name` and `password` both are wrong then its showing right alert msg . But When the `user` matched and `password` not matched then its always return `alert("successfully loggedin")`

Comment: Then check your comparePassword function.

Comment: below is my compare password function and there is nothing seems like error. `UserSchema.methods.comparePassword = function (passw, cb) {
    bcrypt.compare(passw, this.password, function (err, isMatch) {
        if (err) {
            return cb(err);
        }
        cb(null, isMatch);
    });
};`